# determinant is one of the eigenvalue of a 2x2 matrix, geometrical implication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, geometric-topology, conformal-geometry

I got this special 2x2 matrix in the middle of deriving some other stuff, looks it's a bit unique,

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 -x^2/(1+z) & xy/(1+z) \\
xy/(1+z) & 1 -y^2/(1+z) \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where, 
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2=1,   
-1<x,y,z<1
$$

It can be shown eigenvalues are constant 1 and z, respectively, while determinant is z, is there any special geometrical meaning of this matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Since $(x,y,z)$ is a point on a sphere, let switch to spherical coordinates.

$(x,y,z):\begin{cases}
x=\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)\\
y=\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\\
z=\cos(\phi)\end{cases}$

$1+z=1+\cos(\phi)=2\cos^2(\frac {\phi}2)$

Thus the matrix becomes

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 
1-\dfrac{x^2}{1+z} & \dfrac{xy}{1+z}\\
\dfrac{xy}{1+z} & 1-\dfrac{x^2}{1+z}\\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1-2\cos(\theta)^2\sin(\frac {\phi}2)^2 & 2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)\sin(\frac {\phi}2)^2\\
2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)\sin(\frac {\phi}2)^2 & 1-2\sin(\theta)^2\sin(\frac {\phi}2)^2\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Let's now consider the rotation matrix $R(\theta)$ and the dilatation matrix $D(z)$

$R(\theta)=\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{bmatrix}\qquad D(z)=\begin{bmatrix} z & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

A bit of calculation and trigonometric formulas are involved but you can verify that

$$\begin{align}A&=R^{-1}DR\\\\A&=R(-\theta)D(z)R(\theta)\end{align}$$

Although we have broken $A$ into its core elements, I still have hard time figuring out the general meaning of such a geometric transformation in $2$D-space.